# Prototyping and simulating embedded software on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, embedded, visual-studio-express, rtos, prototyping

I am looking for tools and techniques for prototyping (virtual prototyping), simulation, and testing of deeply embedded C code on desktop Windows, including building realistic embedded front panels consisting of buttons, LEDs, and LCD displays (both segmented and graphic).

I'm specifically interested in a possibly low-level approach, using pure C code and raw Win32 API rather than MFC, .NET/C#, vxWidgets or Qt. I'd also like to use free development tools, such as Visual C++ Express with Platform SDK and ResEdit for editing resources.

I'm looking for code examples to render graphic LCDs (from monochrome to 24-bit color) with efficient pixel-level interface, multi-segment LCDs, and owner-drawn buttons that respond both to "depressed" and "released" events.

Comment: voted to close as not a real question. This question is unanswerable as it calls for speculation on what the person actually is even asking.  Maybe simulating Arduinos and some hardware that you might wire up to an arduino? Maybe something else? Who can say.

Comment: Large number of embedded systems, such as: home appliances, thermostats, printers, remote controls, medical devices, test equipment, industrial controllers, etc. come with non-trivial user interface consisting of LCDs (both segmented and increasingly graphical), LEDs, knobs, buttons. To develop software for such devices on the desktop, the UI components need to be emulated with the GUI. I'm looking for such GUI components written in plain Win32 API in C for easy integration with embedded code to be developed and tested on the desktop Windows.

Comment: How about using your web browser as the prototyping platform? HTML5 + fast JScript...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am surprised that my original question triggered so many misunderstandings and adverse comments. The strategy of developing deeply embedded C code on one machine (e.g., a PC) and running it on another (the embedded microcontroller) is called "dual targeting" and is really quite common. For example, developing and testing deeply embedded code on the PC is the cornerstone of the recent book "Test-Driven Development for Embedded C" by James Grenning.

**Avoiding Target Hardware Bottleneck with Dual Targeting**

Please note that dual targeting does not mean that the embedded device has anything to do with the PC. Neither it means that the simulation must be cycle-exact with the embedded target CPU.

Dual targeting simply means that from day one, your embedded code (typically in C) is designed to run on at least two platforms: the final target hardware and your PC. All you really need for this is two C compilers: one for the PC and another for the embedded device.

However, the dual targeting strategy does require a specific way of designing the embedded software such that any target hardware dependencies are handled through a well-defined interface often called the Board Support Package (BSP). This interface has at least two implementations: one for the actual target and one for the PC, for example running Windows. With such interface in place, the bulk of the embedded code can remain completely unaware which BSP implementation it is linked to and so it can be developed quickly on the PC, but can also run on the target hardware *without any changes*.

While some embedded programmers can view dual targeting as a self-inflicted burden, the more experienced developers generally agree that paying attention to the boundaries between software and hardware is actually beneficial, because it results in more modular, more portable, and more maintainable software with much longer useful lifetime. The investment in dual targeting has also an immediate payback in the vastly accelerated compile-run-debug cycle, which is much faster and more productive on the powerful PC compared to much slower, recourse-constrained deeply embedded target with limited visibility into the running code.

**Front Panel Win32 GUI Toolkit**

When developing embedded code for devices with non-trivial user interfaces, one often runs into the problem of representing the embedded front panels as GUI elements on the PC. The problem is so common, that I'm really surprised that nobody here could recommend an existing library or an open source project, which would provide a simple C-only interface to the basic elements, such as LCDs, buttons, and LEDs. This is really not that complicated, yet it seems that every embedded developer has to re-invent this wheel over and over again.

So, to help embedded developers interested in prototyping embedded devices on Windows, I have created a "Front Panel Win32 GUI Toolkit" and have posted it online under the GPL open source license (see http://www.state-machine.com/win32). This toolkit relies only on the raw Win32 API in C and currently provides the following elements:

1. Dot-matrix display for an efficient, pixel-addressable displays such as graphical LCDs, OLEDs, etc. with up to 24-bit color
2. Segment display for segmented display such as segment LCDs, and segment LEDs with generic, custom bitmaps for the segments.
3. Owner-drawn buttons with custom “depressed” and “released” bitmaps and capable of generating separate events when depressed and when released.

The toolkit comes with an example and an App Note (see http://www.state-machine.com/win32/AN_Win32-GUI.pdf), showing how to handle input from the owner-drawn buttons, regular buttons, keyboard, and the mouse. You can also view an animated demo at http://www.state-machine.com/win32/front_panel.html.

Regarding the size and complexity of the "Front Panel Win32 GUI Toolkit", the implementation of the aforementioned GUI elements takes only about 250 lines of C. The example with all sources of input and a lot of comments amounts to some 300 lines of C. The toolkit has been tested with the free Visual C++ Express 2010 (with the Express Edition Platform SDK) and the free ResEdit resource editor.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is a much better answer than the original question! If you articulated your question to this level, you may have received answers that were more satisfying for you. You never mentioned "dual targeting" or "abstracting out hardware dependancies via interfaces" in your original question.

Comment: A variation on this approach I've used occasionally is to write the embedded code in C, but in such a way that it can also compile under C++ on the PC, with I/O registers defined as class objects.  Some kinds of I/O are encapsulated within methods that are different on the PC versus the embedded hardware, but others are handled by letting the embedded system code write what it thinks are real I/O addresses directly.

Answer (score 1):

The appliances you mention in your comment clarification to the question will never be using a windows PC, so low level windows programming is not a requirement in that case. In fact, I'd say its undesirable. Prototyping is about speed. It's about how fast you can put something together to show potential investors or upper management or some other decision maker.

You wouldn't want to spend the extra time with low level C and Win32 api until the project requirements were flushed out enough that you knew that was an absolute requirement for the final project deliverables (*perhaps a server/PC monitoring tool?*). Until then you want speed of development. Lucky for you the industry has tools for rapid prototyping and development of hardware like you describe.

### My Preference for Prototyping with Embedded Development

As for my opinion as a developer, I like the .net microframework (.netmf) simply because I'm already a Microsoft .Net developer and can transfer a lot of my existing skills. Therefor I prototype with a FEZ microcontroller using C# under Visual C# Express 2010 (free as you required). Its fast, easy and you are working on the core of your project in minutes.

If your experience as a developer is different, you may look for a micro controller which is programmed using BASIC, Java or some other language to help with the speed of development by reusing your core skill set.

### Addressing your Question Bounty Comments

> Astonishingly large portions of the embedded software can be developed
>   on the desktop computer as opposed on the deeply embedded target. This
>   avoidance of the "target system bottleneck" can potentially improve
>   productivity by an order of magnitude, if done right. However, to
>   develop embedded software on the desktop, one needs to simulate the UI
>   components, such as displays (both segmented and increasingly
>   graphical), LEDs, knobs, and buttons. I'm looking for such UI
>   components written in plain Win32 API in C for easy integration with
>   embedded code to be developed and tested on the desktop Windows.

I did embedded development full time professionally for well over 4 years as well as many years surrounding that part time. While what you said above is somewhat true, it will not save you time or money which is why everyone is confused about the motivation for this strategy. We spent years trying to put out a windows emulator for this company's hardware devices that would theoretically save time for prototyping. It was always a pain and we spent many more hours of work trying to emulate the experience than if we just went straight from sketched UI drawing specs to real development. The emulator lagged behind hardware development and often wouldn't support the latest features until 6 months or more after the hardware was released. It was a lot of extra work for very little value.

You will spend more of your time developing non-reusable win32 platform code and hardware emulation components than actually writing the code for the core project itself. This only ever makes sense for hardware vendors who provide this emulator as a 'value add' tool to potential 3rd party developers, but it does not make sense for prototyping new hardware designs.

Modern development environments like Visual C# Express 2010 with a FEZ microcontroller can compile, push the project output to the microcontroller, and then begin debugging just as fast *or faster* than you could compile and run a low level windows app in C emulating LCDs or LEDs or switches, etc... So your comment, "improve productivity by an order of magnitude", is simply no longer true with modern tools. (It may have been prior to the last 10 years or so.)

If you really, truly just want to simulate the embedded hardware visually on a PC use something like adobe flash to mock up a UI. But don't duplicate code by coding for windows when the final device you are prototyping won't be running windows (maybe it will be, but you didn't say that). Use the fastest most reliable prototyping tools available today, which is *unequivocally not* low level C and win32 api!

### Maybe use StackExchange for Electronics?

Because this is a development oriented site, discussion about the merits of specific embedded hardware isn't really relevant. If you decide to refocus on using microcontroller electronics for prototyping ([Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/), [FEZ](http://www.ghielectronics.com/), [Propeller](http://www.parallax.com/propeller/), [Basic Stamp](http://www.parallax.com/tabid/436/Default.aspx), [Pololu](http://www.pololu.com/), etc) you might ask for electronics hardware advice on [stackexchange for electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). I will say that most of those platforms are designed to facilitate the prototyping of LCDs, LEDs, buttons and interfaces as you outlined. You can usually assemble a few pre-built modules in a matter of minutes and be ready to start coding your project. Huge time savings can be had here.

Comment: This answer is a complete misunderstanding of my problem. Please see my answer below for the explanation of the dual targeting strategy for developing embedded code on the desktop. The goal is *not* simulating the hardware. The goal is to develop the basic logic and handling user interface of the device. .NET and C# are irrelevant in the context of deeply embedded microcontrollers (MSP430, AVR, Cortex-M0/M3). The comment about slower development on the desktop with GHz clock speeds and GB of memory compared to an embedded MCUs is ridiculous and indicates wrong approach on the desktop.

Comment: @Miro you should have commented earlier while your bounty was still active. FYI, I have several years of dual targeting and embedded development experience. If the tools do not pre-exist from a microcontroller manufacturer YOU WILL be doing lots of extra development and debugging to support your dual targeting approach. You will spend more time/money and not less. This time is not due to "clock speed" or "memory size" its due to duplication of work and spending time writing/debugging "tools" instead of your actual project. This is my experience over several years and is not "ridiculous".

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for too much you need to take a look @ proteus.
http://www.labcenter.com/products/vsm_overview.cfm

Comment: This answer is misunderstanding of my problem. I've never asked for a cycle-exact simulation of the complete embedded system with the CPU and peripherals. All I'm asking for is the ability to run the embedded C code on the PC and represent embedded user interface as GUI elements on Windows.

Comment: Proteus will do so beside the ability to debug your code and  circuit design too.

Answer (score 0):

As Mahmoud said, you may find your code solution with prototyping example in [proteus professional](http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.com/2013/01/proteus-professional-v78-sp2-free.html). It is one of popular software for prototyping, simulation and coding, you can [download proteus professional](http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.com/2013/01/proteus-professional-v78-sp2-free.html) for free and check their manual.

Best of luck