# System testing of Control System

Tags: testing, embedded

We are developing software for Control System of machinery. In the final product the software will be deployed on an ECU with real time operating system but we have the possibility to run the software on PC in emulation mode. Can we perform System level testing using the PC emulation mode only without the ECU hardware or it would be wrong to call that System testing? If it's not correct then what would be the right test level name to describe this test activity?

Comment: Prototype testing?

Comment: If you have system requirements that you can test with the emulation, you can call this system testing. But you *need* additional tests on the real target. There are lots of ressources about testing and its wording, you might like to search for ISTQB.

Comment: We have no System requirements on the ECU software level. The System requirements are written on the machinery level which includes many sensors and other hardware components besides the ECU.

Comment: Perhaps your question is related to this existing StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702040/prototyping-and-simulating-embedded-software-on-windows

Comment: You can call it what you like, others can disagree with your terminology, but it is a matter of opinion so off-topic, and will not have any impact on the success or otherwise of your project.  The only problem you might have is that if you are going to perform testing in real hardware, what are you then going to call that?  You need to clearly distinguish them, that is all.  Perhaps _system software test_ and _system integration test_.  In both cases a _system_ is being tested, it is just a matter of boundaries.